# How do I move table to the middle of the webpage in Python + Dash + Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to move a table to the middle of the screen on a webpage. I have the following code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chriddyp/'
    'c78bf172206ce24f77d6363a2d754b59/raw/'
    'c353e8ef842413cae56ae3920b8fd78468aa4cb2/'
    'usa-agricultural-exports-2011.csv')

def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=10):
    return (

        # Header
        html.Table([html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +

        # Body
        [html.Tr([
            html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
        ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]
    ))


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div([dcc.Input(id='my-id1', value='initial value', type='text')]),
    html.Div([dcc.Input(id='my-id2', value='initial value', type='text')]),
    html.Div([dcc.Input(id='my-id3', value='initial value', type='text')]),
    html.H4(children='US Agriculture Exports (2011)'),
    generate_table(df)
])

app.css.append_css({
    'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'
})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Which makes a webpage that looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

I've tried using 'margin-top' and 'margin-left' to move the table and the input boxes but they don't work how I want them to. They create a lot of white space which is not what I'm looking to do. I just want to move the table to the middle of the page and bring the input boxes down.

I tried using 'columns' which I read was a good way to organise the page, but that didn't work either. Could it be that plotly table doesn't work well with Dash?

Is there another solution to this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to work on the template layout part. Basically there are three major changes I made,

1. Divided your output into row
2. Split the row into 2 parts
3. Added a margin for the left part to make sure the input box falls in between the screen

Here is the code. And I have also attached the screenshot of the output as you had desired.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chriddyp/'
    'c78bf172206ce24f77d6363a2d754b59/raw/'
    'c353e8ef842413cae56ae3920b8fd78468aa4cb2/'
    'usa-agricultural-exports-2011.csv')

def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=10):
    return (

        # Header
        html.Table([html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +

        # Body
        [html.Tr([
            html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
        ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]
    ))


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(children=[

    html.Div([dcc.Input(id='my-id1', value='initial value', type='text')]),
    html.Div([dcc.Input(id='my-id2', value='initial value', type='text')]),
    html.Div([dcc.Input(id='my-id3', value='initial value', type='text')])],

    className='two columns', style={'margin-top': '42vh'}),



    html.Div(children=[html.H4(children='US Agriculture Exports (2011)'),
                       generate_table(df)], className='ten columns')
], className='row' )

app.css.append_css({
    'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'
})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

** Output**
[image: Screenshot of the output]